# Bootstrap at 1180?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, width

I had someone design a website for me, which I'm going to build in bootstrap 3. The designer had mentioned that the design was built from a 1180 bootstrap layout, and I'm having a hard time finding out what that is. I assumed that instead of using 1200, 980, 768 ect... I would use 1180, 964.5, 755.85 ect... But when I opened the .ai files I received from her, the document width was 1200px and the container width was 940px (970px in bootstrap due to the 15px padding on the left and right). Should I just set the main width to 1200px and the container width to 940px and just begin building it from there? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ootstrap use `box-sizing: border-box;` everywhere, that means that paddings doesn't increase the div size.

If we take a look on `bootstrap.css`, we can see :

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* ... */
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

So, in large devices, you'll use a 1170px layout, *including* 15px paddings.

If you wanna use a 940px container, you can ass this CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: 115px;
    padding-left: 115px;
  }
}
```

Then :

- in large devices you'll have a 940px container's width (plus 115px paddings)
- in medium devices you'll have a 940px container's width (plus 15px paddings)
- in large devices you'll have a 720px container's width (plus 15px paddings)
- in large devices you'll have a 100% container's width (without paddings)

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/113298#)